# performSegue is not entered but no error is generated

Tags: swift3

In swift3 I have done multiple segue's but in my latest one when I do one:
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registrationSettions", sender: self)

where registrationSettings is a "show" segue to my RegistrationViewController class.

In xcode 8 it just steps over the performSegue call without doing a transition into the view controller code (I have a break point in it in the viewDidLoad (first line) and it isn't reached).  And no errors are generated to the system console.

I have over 15 other classes where doing segue's work just fine.  So my question is under what cases can performSegue be used where the view controller isn't entered and no errors are generated in the system console?  I know that the segue specified is correct because I have tried spelling it incorrectly and I get an error in the system console.  I have also used a segue link to a view controller that works and the transition works fine.

I have deleted and re-added the view controller and deleted and re-added the structure for it in the Storybook and it still acts the same.

I can add the code but I don't know how I would show the Storybook structure.  But it still comes back to why the performSegue call is stepped through in Xcode without transitioning into the view controller code and no errors are generated to the system window.

Has anyone seen this behavior?  I have done several days of surfing and haven't found anyone who gets this behavior.  Usually it results in errors in the system console.

Comment: Is registrationSettions a typo?

Comment: Did you say `viewDidLoad()` isn't getting called? Thats an indicator that its not your segue but the setup of the view controller connected to the Storyboard. Make sure the view controller in the storyboard is correct UIViewController subclass you're trying to use

Comment: Sorry about the stupid question but how to do I make sure the view controller is using the correct UIViewController subclass? Thanks.

Comment: To be more clear is am using a "override func viewDidLoad() {" in my "class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{".  Is the override on the viewDidLoad() make it a subclass in the UIViewController class?

Comment: I have figured out my problem